# HTML input pattern with lower key letters, numbers and a comma

Tags: html, regex, forms

Someone here, who is familiar with html patterns (regular expressions)?
I need an input pattern rule that only allows strings like this:
**anke1**
**anke1,our4**
**anke1,our4,tim2**
**anke1,our4,tim2,next4**
..and so on

- The input string only allows 3 or 4 lower key characters [a-z]{3,4}
- The numbers between 0 and 9 (but only one number) [0-9]{1}
- After each string there is a comma. (**The first and the last string has no comma!**)
- The string has no length restrictions.

  `<form><input type="text" name"test" pattern="???"></form>`

Maybe someone knows how to put all these rules together for an input pattern.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to your rule,
This regex will help you. It is working for me.

```
^([a-z]{3}[0-9]{1}[,]{1})*$
```

Comment: There is only one problem.
There needs to be a comma after every string with your pattern.
Do you know a regular expresion that the first and the last string doesn't have a comma?

Comment: comma is need for every string. In this regex three letters , 1 number and 1 comma is compulsory and i have tested according to this

Comment: Your right and thank's for your work, but do you know a regular expresion that the first and the last string doesn't have a comma?
(I updated my main question above).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be use full if you only make single string. If you have log string than same as I explained. For you case it also work in all you scenario. I have tested it is working

Comment: I found it out myself! :P

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem by myself:

```
^([a-z]{3,4}[0-9]{1}|[a-z]{3,4}[0-9]{1}[,]{1})*$
```